# Definitive Saudi self-transfer Q&A

Tags: discussion

Ever since Saudi started opening up, we're getting a *lot* of questions about people (mostly but not entirely Indian) doing self-transfers on LCCs via Riyadh.  Can we draft a canonical answer to these?

Comment: Yes please, post a canonical question or pick an early question after the opening up and edit that to a canonical one. Than we can have someone post a canonical answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

10 upvotes and 0 downvotes is clear enough, so here's a first cut:

[I am transiting through Saudi Arabia. Do I need a visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185294/i-am-transiting-through-saudi-arabia-do-i-need-a-visa#185295)

Please expand, in particular for the corner case of transiting on separate tickets without checked baggage.